# Обработка исключений, скорость

Tags: c#

У меня в конторе, где я работаю, есть множество кастомных библиотек. В том числе есть свой DAL для базы данных MSSQL. В DAL любая ошибка которая приходит из ридера, не важно это хранимая процедура или просто SQL запрос, переконвертируеться в `applicationexception`. И уже на стороне UI - клиента, выскакивает окно, которое абсолютно все роняет, если не заключить это в `try catch`.

Недавно была ситуация, когда у меня падал клиент, на добавлении дубликата. Ибо сохранение сущности шло через хранимую процедуру и дубликатом считается не только ключ, но и одно важное поле.

По логике вещей, если мне приходит из базы SQL Exception, я могу на стороне UI его обработать, по коду ошибки. Считайте что стандартная схема обработки исключений от более частных (специфичных) до общих.

В ответ на мои рассуждения я услышал некоторые слова :

> Играть в обработку абсолютно всех исключений не имеет смысла, и потом
>   исключения медленно работают, если у тебя приходит ошибка из DAL, надо
>   выбить `MessageBox` с сообщением и в лог кидать `StackTrace`, не стоит
>   акцентировать внимание на то что может произойти 1 раз из 1000

На сколько верна данная позиция? Если есть вероятность дубликата, стоит пользователя уведомить о том что имеется дублирование значений, а не кидать MessageBox с сообщением по типу "Введенные значения не удовлетворяют условиям, свяжитесь с администратором"

А также интересует скорость обработки исключений на .net, на сколько сильно они тормозят работу.

Comment: В идеале клиенту вообще не должна даваться возможность вводить ошибочные данные. Но говоря о вашем вопросе - я считаю, что это совсем не user-friendly на все отвечать стандартным мессаджем.

Comment: @AGS17 есть такая парадигма как "сбор данных - обработка данных - работа с данными" в момент ввода данных, каким образом я узнаю что ему можно вводить в то самое поле которое не должно быть дубликатом. И вопрос стоит о том правильно ли работать с исключениями, так как мне сказали. или лучше всего обрабатывать их осмысленно.

Comment: не совсем правильно выразился: _не должна даваться возможность_ - подразумевалось валидировать при смене фокуса и тут же сообщать, если не валидно.
Я всегда стараюсь обрабатывать эксепшны осмысленно в своих проектах. В вашем случае скорее подходит первый вариант, ибо "заказчик (в вашем случае - ваш работодатель, если я правильно понял) всегда прав".

Comment: Медленная не обработка, медленная генерация и сбор стектрейса

Comment: @AGS17 то есть всякий раз когда у меня открывается форма, я должен кешировать более 10т сущностей из базы и не факт что на момент заполнения формы, какая либо из сущностей не изменится (удалится, изменится, добавится). При смене фокуса валидировать удобно конкретные поля. Допустим строка должна быть длинной не более 100 символов и не менее 10, зачем утруждать пользователя ловить эксепшены в лицо по кнопке ОК, когда можно окрасить textbox в красное, и сделать тултип. В вопросе прямая зависимость - база которая порождает исключения и клиент который обязан их правильно обработать

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне, то вы пришли к правильной схеме обработки исключений. Думаю, что вам просто хотели сказать, что не нужно тут же бросаться писать десятки блоков `catch` на каждый тип исключения, вот и все. Да, в большинстве случаев есть один блок `catch` и всё, но во всех остальных случаях - пара-тройка "специфичных" блоков `catch` и один "общий" для одного блока `try`. Это нормально. У меня на дню иногда по десятку звонков раздается, когда я показываю на UI ошибку по типу "Неверно введенные данные". Потом стоит добавить catch для самого частого исключения, для которого покажется читабельный текст с описанием проблемы, и  воцаряет спокойствие. Но, повторюсь, не делать ведь этого для каждого типа исключений.